# Electron oauth callback

Tags: reactjs, oauth, electron

I'm trying to implement an oauth 1.0a flow in an Electron app using react-router. Here is the code for the request to the oauth server.

```
    const postBody = {
    url: https://oauthserver,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    oauth: {
      callback: url.format({
        pathname: 'C:/oauth',
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
      }),
      consumer_key: config.get('consumerKey'),
      consumer_secret: config.get('consumerSecret')
    }
  };
  return request.post(postBody).then(data => {
    const requestToken = qs.parse(data);
    config.set('oauthTokenSecret', requestToken.oauth_token_secret);
    config.set('oauthToken', requestToken.oauth_token);
    return requestToken;
  });
```

This callback would take place in a new authWindow which gets opened here,

```
exports.openOauthWindow = token => {
  const authWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }
  });
  authWindow.loadURL('https://oauthserver.com/Begin?oauth_token=' + token, {
    extraHeaders: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" \nmode: "no-cors"'
  });
  authWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', (e, newURL) => {
    console.log('NEW URL');
    console.log(newURL);
  });
  return authWindow;
};
```

But i get a 'not allowed to load local resource' error in the authWindow. If i use the 'https://localhost:8080' redirect i used in the web app then the authWindow gets a raw 'chromewebdata' url.

Any ideas on how to properly do this would be appreciated.

Comment: callbacks are meant for webapps, but for desktop apps, you have to use 'oob'

Comment: The oauth provider i'm using doesn't support out of band.

Comment: Potentially useful: [AppAuth-JS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS) "_The library is designed for use in Web Apps, Node.js CLI applications, Chrome Apps and applications that use Electron or similar frameworks._"